# Global variables not being defined in Typescript

Tags: socket.io, typescript

I'm trying to create a socket.io connection from server to client using typescript, for which I need to define the "socket" object in a constructor so the object can emit data to the client using socket. However, the socket object does not get defined as a variable of that class when compiled to javascript which prevents it from being called.

Here's the typescript.

export class Upload {

```
directory = "./data";
socket: Socket;

constructor(socket:Socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public upload(req:express.Request, res) {
                this.socket.emit('fileReceivedConfirmation', {
                    successful:true,
                    filePath: filePath,
                    originalName: originalFileName
                });
    }
```

Here's the corresponding javascript

```
function Upload(socket) {
    this.directory = "./data";
    this.socket = socket;
}

Upload.prototype.upload = function (req, res) {
      this.socket.emit('fileReceivedConfirmation', {
                successful: true,
                filePath: filePath,
                originalName: originalFileName
            });
}
```

The socket variable is not defined anywhere in the compiled Javascript - which creates this error, when the function calls socket.

```
C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\Core\lib\Upload.js:43
            this.socket.emit('fileReceivedConfirmation', {
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the variables to static and it worked:

```
directory = "./data";
static socket:Socket;

constructor(socket:Socket) {
    console.log("Creating socket");
    Upload.socket = socket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following code

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
});
```

To this

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket:any):void => {
        this.socket = socket;
    });
```

Comment: Sorry the problem has changes. Please check the question. Thanks.

Comment: The error indicates that you didn't assign any value to `socket` parameter. How do you initializing the Upload constructor?